# AmChart 5 - Globe view is not showing full globe and home location is not focused

Tags: javascript, angular, amcharts, amcharts5

I am using AmChart v5 for creating a map in globe/map view.

My expectation is - When I switch to globe view from actual flat map view then

- either it should show the whole globe with the home location focused at the center
- or globe should appear with the home location area focused (zoomed in) and if I zoom out manually it should show the whole globe in the center.

But look at the results in this screenshot that I got. After toggle the globe view looks broken and not showing as expected.
https://i.postimg.cc/GmQSVCDb/Map-Globe-Toggle-Not-Working-1.png

Here is the code that I am using

`

```
      var chart = root.container.children.push(am5map.MapChart.new(root, {
        panX: "translateX",
        panY: "translateY",
        wheelSensitivity: 0.7,
        projection: am5map.geoMercator(),
        homeZoomLevel: 3,
        homeGeoPoint: { longitude: -0.1262, latitude: 51.5002 },
        minZoomLevel: 1,
        maxZoomLevel: 16
      }));


      var switchButton = cont.children.push(am5.Button.new(root, {
        themeTags: ["switch"],
        centerY: am5.p50,
        icon: am5.Circle.new(root, {
          themeTags: ["icon"]
        })
      }));

      switchButton.on("active", function () {
        if (!switchButton.get("active")) {
          chart.set("projection", am5map.geoMercator());
          chart.set("panX", "translateX");
          chart.set("panY", "translateY");
        }
        else {
          chart.set("projection", am5map.geoOrthographic());
          chart.set("panX", "rotateX");
          chart.set("panY", "rotateY");
        }
      });
```

`

Look at the "Animated Map" section in this article.
I was trying to achieve similar kind of map-globe functionality
(although not exactly the same)

https://preview.keenthemes.com/html/metronic/docs/charts/amcharts/maps

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>

<head></head>
<style></style>

<!-- Resources -->
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/map.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/geodata/worldLow.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/5/themes/Animated.js"></script>

<body>
    <div id="chartdiv" style="width: 600px;height: 500px;background:#171717;margin: 0 auto;padding: 30px;"></div>
    <script>

        am5.ready(function () {

            var root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");

            root.setThemes([
                am5themes_Animated.new(root)
            ]);

            var chart = root.container.children.push(am5map.MapChart.new(root, {
                panX: "translateX",
                panY: "translateY",
                wheelSensitivity: 0.7,
                projection: am5map.geoMercator(),
                homeZoomLevel: 3,
                homeGeoPoint: { longitude: -0.1262, latitude: 51.5002 },
                minZoomLevel: 1,
                maxZoomLevel: 16
            }));

            var cont = chart.children.push(am5.Container.new(root, {
                layout: root.horizontalLayout,
                x: 20,
                y: 40
            }));

            cont.children.push(am5.Label.new(root, {
                centerY: am5.p50,
                text: "Map"
            }));

            var switchButton = cont.children.push(am5.Button.new(root, {
                themeTags: ["switch"],
                centerY: am5.p50,
                icon: am5.Circle.new(root, {
                    themeTags: ["icon"]
                })
            }));

            switchButton.on("active", function () {
                if (!switchButton.get("active")) {
                    chart.set("projection", am5map.geoMercator());
                    chart.set("panX", "translateX");
                    chart.set("panY", "translateY");
                }
                else {
                    chart.set("projection", am5map.geoOrthographic());
                    chart.set("panX", "rotateX");
                    chart.set("panY", "rotateY");
                }
            });

            cont.children.push(
                am5.Label.new(root, {
                    centerY: am5.p50,
                    text: "Globe"
                })
            );
            var backgroundSeries = chart.series.push(am5map.MapPolygonSeries.new(root, {}));
            backgroundSeries.mapPolygons.template.setAll({
                fill: root.interfaceColors.get("alternativeBackground"),
                fillOpacity: 0,
                strokeOpacity: 0
            });

            backgroundSeries.data.push({
                geometry: am5map.getGeoRectangle(90, 180, -90, -180)
            });

            var polygonSeries = chart.series.push(
                am5map.MapPolygonSeries.new(root, {
                    geoJSON: am5geodata_worldLow,
                    exclude : ["AQ"]
                })
            );
            polygonSeries.set('fill', am5.color(0x2f2f2f));
            
            var lineSeries = chart.series.push(am5map.MapLineSeries.new(root, {}));
            lineSeries.mapLines.template.setAll({
                stroke: root.interfaceColors.get("alternativeBackground"),
                strokeOpacity: 0.3
            });

            var pointSeries = chart.series.push(am5map.MapPointSeries.new(root, {}));
            var colorset = am5.ColorSet.new(root, {});

            pointSeries.bullets.push(function () {
                var container = am5.Container.new(root, {});

                var circle = container.children.push(
                    am5.Circle.new(root, {
                        radius: 4,
                        tooltipY: 0,
                        fill: "#01a982",
                        strokeOpacity: 0,
                        tooltipText: "{title}"
                    })
                );

                return am5.Bullet.new(root, {
                    sprite: container
                });
            });

            var cities = [
                {
                    title: "Brussels",
                    latitude: 50.8371,
                    longitude: 4.3676
                },
                {
                    title: "Copenhagen",
                    latitude: 55.6763,
                    longitude: 12.5681
                },
                {
                    title: "Paris",
                    latitude: 48.8567,
                    longitude: 2.351
                },
                {
                    title: "Reykjavik",
                    latitude: 64.1353,
                    longitude: -21.8952
                },
                {
                    title: "Moscow",
                    latitude: 55.7558,
                    longitude: 37.6176
                },
                {
                    title: "Madrid",
                    latitude: 40.4167,
                    longitude: -3.7033
                },
                {
                    title: "London",
                    latitude: 51.5002,
                    longitude: -0.1262,
                    url: "http://www.google.co.uk"
                },
                {
                    title: "Peking",
                    latitude: 39.9056,
                    longitude: 116.3958
                },
                {
                    title: "New Delhi",
                    latitude: 28.6353,
                    longitude: 77.225
                },
                {
                    title: "Tokyo",
                    latitude: 35.6785,
                    longitude: 139.6823,
                    url: "http://www.google.co.jp"
                },
                {
                    title: "Ankara",
                    latitude: 39.9439,
                    longitude: 32.856
                },
                {
                    title: "Buenos Aires",
                    latitude: -34.6118,
                    longitude: -58.4173
                },
                {
                    title: "Brasilia",
                    latitude: -15.7801,
                    longitude: -47.9292
                },
                {
                    title: "Ottawa",
                    latitude: 45.4235,
                    longitude: -75.6979
                },
                {
                    title: "Washington",
                    latitude: 38.8921,
                    longitude: -77.0241
                },
                {
                    title: "Kinshasa",
                    latitude: -4.3369,
                    longitude: 15.3271
                },
                {
                    title: "Cairo",
                    latitude: 30.0571,
                    longitude: 31.2272
                },
                {
                    title: "Pretoria",
                    latitude: -25.7463,
                    longitude: 28.1876
                }
            ];

            for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
                var city = cities[i];
                addCity(city.longitude, city.latitude, city.title);
            }

            function addCity(longitude, latitude, title) {
                pointSeries.data.push({
                    geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [longitude, latitude] },
                    title: title
                });
            }

            // Make stuff animate on load
            chart.appear(1000, 100);

        }); // end am5.ready()
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```